# ubuntu 20.04 cronjob at restart not working

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I have a bash file that just stops the existing docker container. The script works fine when I run it manually but it is not working on my crontab. I need to execute the bash script when I start my pc.

**Crontab:(not working on start)**

```
@reboot /var/www/airflow/stop_airflow.sh
```

**Bash content (stop_airflow.sh)**

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /var/www/airflow && docker-compose stop
```

**Terminal Execution:**

```
bash /var/www/airflow/stop_airflow.sh
```

**Outputs:**

```
Stopping airflow_airflow-worker_1    ... done 
Stopping airflow_flower_1            ... done 
Stopping airflow_airflow-webserver_1 ... done 
Stopping airflow_airflow-scheduler_1 ... done 
Stopping airflow_redis_1             ... done 
Stopping airflow_postgres_1          ... done
```

Comment: yes, it is 20.04 but why down votes?

Comment: Does your script have exec bit `+x`?

Comment: yes it has the `+x`

Comment: Isn't docker managed by systemd?

Answer (score 2):

Jobs run through `cron` aren't run in the same runtime environment that you have on your desktop.  None of your `PATH` changes, or other environment  variable settings from `~/.bashrc` are automatically propagated to  your `cron` job. For example, there's no `$DISPLAY`, so GUI programs need special treatment (read `man xhost`). In your case, your script is probably looking for, and not finding `docker-compose` in your `$PATH`.

One can set environment variables for all one's `cron` jobs in the `crontab` file
Read `man 5 crontab`.

Look at the results of  `echo "=== id ===";id;echo "=== set ===";set;echo "=== env ===";env | sort;echo "=== alias ===";alias` in each of your environments.